# R gbm package: Training Error and Adaboost exponential loss function

Tags: r, machine-learning, adaboost

I am using gbm package in R for **binary classification**. I am using adaboost exponential loss function for the algorithm. I have two questions:

1. If I want to see the training error, should I just look at this? (Suppose my model object is called fit, and I used 3-fold CV.)

   `best.iter <- gbm.perf(fit,method="cv")`

   `fit$train.error[best.iter]`
2. If I want to do prediction on my training dataset, say "train", with response variable removed, by this line of code: `pred <- predict(object=fit,newdata=train,n.trees=best.iter)`. It is only giving me the exponential loss values of adaboost. How could I transform this back to the probability of the binary class? I tried `plogis` and `log`. The results are just not making sense. For instance, `plogis` gave me 0.99*** for everything, `log` gave me the interval [0.52,0.56]. What kind of transformation should I do?

FYI, I grew 100 trees and the fitting process seems OK. For instance,

```
> fit$oobag.improve
[1] 0.1431295103 0.1093538334 0.0852480128 0.0678520088 0.0549712390 0.0452351232 0.0378058484 0.0319409903
[9] 0.0275396129 0.0237185758 0.0208696658 0.0182786535 0.0163750200 0.0146381260 0.0132728128 0.0119435448
[17] 0.0108959138 0.0099211566 0.0091093166 0.0084316036 0.0078037047 0.0071945142 0.0066821670 0.0061718044
[25] 0.0058103999 0.0054534710 0.0051276913 0.0047975274 0.0044901763 0.0042387273 0.0039702177 0.0037345627
[33] 0.0035337545 0.0033370776 0.0031656407 0.0029688111 0.0028016085 0.0026640768 0.0025268873 0.0023897908
[41] 0.0022594735 0.0021612521 0.0020255227 0.0019376223 0.0018393318 0.0017481065 0.0016463413 0.0015561673
[49] 0.0014813435 0.0014237926 0.0013459092 0.0012719409 0.0012116881 0.0011572038 0.0010948941 0.0010420570
[57] 0.0009843288 0.0009398356 0.0008938670 0.0008542828 0.0008063698 0.0007637763 0.0007325414 0.0006917561
[65] 0.0006582027 0.0006313925 0.0005979843 0.0005645791 0.0005410957 0.0005159002 0.0004869797 0.0004643209
[73] 0.0004464032 0.0004213901 0.0004010297 0.0003815199 0.0003623747 0.0003445184 0.0003269569 0.0003105762
[81] 0.0002960856 0.0002802715 0.0002679399 0.0002541207 0.0002425242 0.0002294759 0.0002200414 0.0002093278
[89] 0.0001974315 0.0001893624 0.0001788743 0.0001709422 0.0001624860 0.0001538988 0.0001479532 0.0001403145
[97] 0.0001338089 0.0001256208 0.0001206701 0.0001142448
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

1.First question: you are correct, by fit$train.error you could check the training error.
fit$train.error[best.iter] is to check training error of the best model chosen. Be careful, fit$train.error[best.iter] is not the smallest training error, because the best model is chosen by cv.test.error.

2.Adaboost is a special case when ensamble model chooses exponential loss function. To transform it back to other type of loss function, you need first to know how adaboos errors have been calculated.

for y{-1,1} classification problem:
exponential loss `L=exp(-y*f(x))`

where f(x) is the result generated by well-trained adaboost model. 
the class decision should be made by the sign of f(x), if f(x)>0 the predict y=1, otherwise y=-1.
Then you could see all exponential loss < 1 have been correctly classified, loss <1 are misclassified. Now it is easy to transform to binary misclassification rate.

Note that don't worry if you see loss function for all train data <1, this is because adaboost optimizes margin rather than reduce misclassification rate.

Hope this can help you!

Comment: To clarify: L>1 means classified, while L<1 should be misclassified right? You typed "<" in both cases.